# How to validate Mono controller response when using WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-webflux

In non-reactive approach (without `Mono`) a similar code below normally throws a validation exception.
But with a reactive approach, the endpoint responds successfully with 200 Ok ignoring `@NotNull` annotation in `ClientResponseDto`.

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Data
public class ClientResponseDto {
    @NotNull
    String id;
} 

***  

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@RestController
@Validated
public class ClientsSearchController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/clients")
    @Valid
    public Mono<ClientResponseDto> getClients() {
        return Mono.just(new ClientResponseDto());
    }
}
```

build.gradle has the following

```
    // spring boot 2.6.3
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    // javax
    implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final"
```

Why `@Valid` and `@Validated` does not work for `Mono` responses?
It it possible to make them work?